# How to add error handling to a class in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling

I'd like to add error handling to a PHP class, just can't figure out how to do it.

I've tried the following:

```
class BaseClass
{
    function errorHandler(int $type, mstring $msg, ?string $file = null, ?int $line = null)
    {
        echo $type . ': ' . $msg . ' in ' . $file . ' on line ' . $line;
        exit;
    }
}


class Attributes extends BaseClass
{
    private $backgroundColor;

    function __construct($attributes)
    {
        set_error_hander("errorHandler", E_ALL);
        $this->backgroundColor = $attributes['backgroundColor'];

        //This line doesn't work
        //set_backgroundColor($attributes['backgroundColor']);
    }

    function get_backgroundColor()
    {
        return $this->backgroundColor;
    }

    function set_backgroundColor($value)
    {
        $this->backgroundColor = $value;
    }
}
```

So I created a BaseClass to provide an error handler 'errorHandler()'.
Then inherited from BaseClass.
In the construtor of the inherited class I've set the error handler as 'errorHandler()'.

I'm new to PHP so some of this is guess work.

Can anyone please help me?

Steve

Comment: You have a typo: `mstring $msg` should be `string $msg`. Also, that doesn't set the error handler for that _class_. It sets the error handler for the entire script. What are you actually trying to solve here? What should your error handler do differently from PHP's default error handler?

Comment: Another typo: `set_error_hander(...);` (you're missing the `l` in `handler`). You can also not reference a class method as if it was a global function. You would need to pass `[$this, 'errorHandler']` instead of `"errorHandler"`. However, this is usually done in one place when you boot the script (since it sets a global handler)

Comment: Why do you want to add error handling "to a class"? It makes no sense. You are adding it not to a class bit to the entire code. And what do you want this error handler to do?

Comment: OK thank you everyone. I will take a look at custom exceptions as suggested below. 

To answer the last point, I just want the error handler to write the error to the screen as I have no debugger. or syntax checking. So really difficult to spot errors. I'm using the VS Code editor so will look at adding some extensions to provide some checks too.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your work and it happens you has made a little mistake.
Currently you need to refer to the current object for calling `errorHandler`

You can do it like this:

```
set_error_handler($this->errorHandler(...));
```

or:

```
set_error_handler(array($this, 'errorHandler'));
```

Also, I (strongly) recommend to create a custom exception instead of using `set_error_handler`.

You can find a lot of [documentation about custom exceptions in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Comment: Yes, please use Exceptions on class level, don't put an error handler into a base-class (even while its fine to explain what the issue was).

Comment: OK thank you for the suggestions, I'll look at exception handling as suggested, thank you once again.